# MySQL: Insert if new OR update if NULL

Tags: mysql

I have this table in MySQL, which i wish to enter if the rows doesn't exist, else update ONLY if they are NULL.

I know about `on duplicate key update` and MySQL if conditional but unable to figure out how to put them in place together.

```
mysql> mysql> describe patients;
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| patient_id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| patient_identifier           | varchar(64)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| issuer_of_patient_identifier | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| medical_record_locator       | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| patient_name                 | varchar(128) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| birth_date                   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| deceased_date                | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gender                       | varchar(16)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ethnicity                    | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_created                 | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_update_date             | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_updated_by              | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Added sample data as requested by Gordon in comments:

```
mysql> select * from patients \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  patient_id: 4909
          patient_identifier: TG18-2002
issuer_of_patient_identifier: 11
      medical_record_locator: MRL 1
                patient_name: AAPM^Test^Patterns
                  birth_date: 1992-07-04 01:02:03
               deceased_date: NULL
                      gender: O
                   ethnicity: North American
                date_created: 2018-01-24 21:32:02
            last_update_date: 2018-01-24 21:32:02
             last_updated_by: indexStore
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Sample MySQL if conditional if null then update:

```
Updating multiple columns in one go:
mysql> update test1234 set col1=IF(col1 IS NULL OR col1 = ' ',70,col1), 
   col2=IF(col2 IS NULL OR col2 = ' ','abracadabra',col2) where col3=8;
```

Comment: What is your question?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added a sample data as you requested. This is same requirement as `on duplicate key update` but update should happen only on NULL rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `IF` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)
VALUES (x, y)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
col1 = IF(col1 IS NULL, VALUES(col1), col1),
col2 = IF(col2 IS NULL, VALUES(col2), col2);
```